# Using DLL's in CPP

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

I am a newbie to CPP. I have a Visual studio project which creates a dll. I need to write a simple code which calls the functions in this dll.

Till now most of the questions I browsed dealt with problems where the dll was called from an external app.

I want a very simple tutorial that introduces this concept. It loads a dll once and then calls its functions repeatedly from a simple code and NOT an app.

A simple example or a link to it will be very helpful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify the points::
1. You have a dll a.dll
2. You have an exe b.exe.
3. You want b.exe to load a.dll and call its exported functions.
Have I understood your ques correctly?

Comment: Consider I have a dll 'myDll.dll'. I want to write a code 'testDll.cpp' which will call the functions in 'myDll.dll'. Did I make any sense now ?

Comment: "Calling dll in cpp" You do realize that the code to write b.exe will contain the exact source code to load and use a.dll...

Comment: I have never used dll's before and hence I have no idea where to start. Can you please provide a very basic code which just loads all the functions in some dll and calls them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic concept is::

1. LoadLibrary: To load the dll.
2. GetProcAddress: To get the address of exported function of the dll.

[MSDN Sample Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms686944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
    // Assuming you have correctly built DLL with exported functions.
    // A simple program that uses LoadLibrary and 
    // GetProcAddress to access myPuts from Myputs.dll.

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 

typedef int (__cdecl *MYPROC)(LPWSTR); 

int main( void ) 
{ 
    HINSTANCE hinstLib; 
    MYPROC ProcAdd; 
    BOOL fFreeResult, fRunTimeLinkSuccess = FALSE; 

    // Get a handle to the DLL module.

    hinstLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("MyPuts.dll")); 

    // If the handle is valid, try to get the function address.

    if (hinstLib != NULL) 
    { 
        ProcAdd = (MYPROC) GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "myPuts"); 

        // If the function address is valid, call the function.

        if (NULL != ProcAdd) 
        {
            fRunTimeLinkSuccess = TRUE;
            (ProcAdd) (L"Message sent to the DLL function\n"); 
        }
        // Free the DLL module.

        fFreeResult = FreeLibrary(hinstLib); 
    } 

    // If unable to call the DLL function, use an alternative.
    if (! fRunTimeLinkSuccess) 
        printf("Message printed from executable\n"); 

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should export a function in dll project.

```
Ex: "ExportFunc"
```

And You can use LoadLibrary, GetProcAddress in other project to use funciton in dll.
Ex:

```
    #include <windows.h> 
      #include <stdio.h> 

    typedef int (__cdecl *MYPROC)(LPWSTR); 

    int main( void ) 

    { 
    HINSTANCE hinstLib; 
    MYPROC ProcAdd; 
    BOOL fFreeResult, fRunTimeLinkSuccess = FALSE; 

    // Get a handle to the DLL module.

    hinstLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("DllName.dll")); 

    // If the handle is valid, try to get the function address.

    if (hinstLib != NULL) 
    { 
        ProcAdd = (MYPRO`enter code here`C) GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "ExportFunction"); 

        // If the function address is valid, call the function.

        if (NULL != ProcAdd) 
        {
            fRunTimeLinkSuccess = TRUE;
            (ProcAdd) (L"Message sent to the DLL function\n"); 
        }
        // Free the DLL module.

        fFreeResult = FreeLibrary(hinstLib); 
    } 

    // If unable to call the DLL function, use an alternative.
    if (! fRunTimeLinkSuccess) 
        printf("Message printed from executable\n"); 

    return 0;

}
```